# how to use melt function in multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has columns like this

```
balance,
2016-10-5,
2016-11-8,
2017-3-7,
2018-5-29
```

and more. my desire output columns like this

```
balance,
date,
values
```

I tried using this script:

`df= pd.melt(df,id_vars=['balance'], value_vars=['2016-10-5,2016-11-8,2017-3-7,2018-5-29'] var_name='date',value_name='values')`

this code worked but columns are too many how to make all date in date columns in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove parameter `value_vars`, check function [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

> **value_vars** : tuple, list, or ndarray, optional
>
> Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars.

```
df= pd.melt(df,id_vars='balance', var_name='date',value_name='values')
```